# How to print using wireless to a Canon MG6150?

Tags: wireless, printing, canon

I have successfully connected my **Canon MG6150** to my laptop, using the "Add Printer" function. However, the print command only works over a USB connection. The laptop connects wirelessly to my BT HomeHub 3 and the internet but when I check the network, none of the other devices on the network are shown. Likewise, when I check the network on my windows-based desktop, it shows everything but this laptop. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When you added the printer, was it connected by USB at the time?

You may need to force it to find it wirelessly by unplugging the printer and then doing "Add -> Network Printer -> Find Network Printer". This worked for me with a Canon MG6250.

Comment: `Find` gives me the result `No printer was found at that address.` Apparently I _must_ enter a `host` but what could that be? [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ZPyfqf6.png) and [my related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/345104/how-to-connect-to-a-wlan-printer).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Find Network Printer and use the printer ip address in order to identify the proper printer.  I have the same printer that method worked for me.

Comment: @Tim This looks like an answer to me..